# Why instead of 128,127 is added to the biased exponent in IEEE 754 floating point representation?

Tags: binary

The smallest number available using 8 signed bits is -128. So, shouldn't 128 be added to the exponent so that -128 becomes 0 ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory: "*a bias is added so that the smallest representable exponent is represented as 1, with 0 used for subnormal numbers*"

Comment: The range of an 8-bit two's complement integer has nothing to do with. They simply didn't choose that range.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks !!